# C function always returns zero to Objective C

Tags: c, objective-c, xcode

I have an Objective C project incorporating a C file with some helper functions. However, functions in the C file that return a `float` are not working as expected.

C file:

```
float returnFloat() {
    return 10.0;
}
```

Meanwhile in an Objective C instance method:

```
float x;
x = returnFloat();
```

x is always 0.000000.

**Edit**

I have a bunch of "implicit declaration" warnings in the Objective C file, relating to use of the functions I have in the C file.

Assignments using functions that return `int` are working fine. Where an assignment is made from a function returning `float`, the debugger says "variable optimized away by compiler".

Is it likely I'm not correctly importing the C file within the Objective-C code? I have just let Xcode link it in automagically. Then, how come the problem only occurs for C functions that return `float`?

Comment: are you sure you are using this declaration?  It should be `float returnFloat() {...}`

Comment: Sorry, yes, have corrected the question. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: That's pretty weird; what does the debugger say?  How about looking at the generated code?  When I have problems like this it almost always ends up being me editing code on one branch, but building and testing from another one....

Comment: I went so far as to make a test project, it works fine here (as you might expect).  Sounds like you have some funny business going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Carl. What I got from the debugger was that, on the x = returnFloat() line, x is described as "<variable optimized away by compiler>".

Comment: Good to hear it tracked things down for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use a .h file, just like with .m files, to declare what you're doing in another file.  So, you need something like this for this scenario (these are incomplete):

**returnfloat.c**

```
float returnFloat() {
    return 10.0;
}
```

**returnfloat.h**

```
float returnFloat(void);
```

**usefloat.m**

```
#import "returnfloat.h"

- (void) someMethod {
    float ten = returnFloat();
}
```

The problem (given away by your "implicit declaration" warnings) is that the compiler is assuming that you are calling something that returns an `int` or `id`, not a `float`. When you work with C, things need to be prototyped (GCC will treat the .c file like C, and all C rules apply, even though you're in an Objective-C project).

---

If you'd like to see an example, here's something from one of my projects -- production code (you can write pure C in a file ending in .m, and GCC will treat it like Objective-C in some ways):

**DebugF.m**

```
#import "DebugF.h"

void __Debug(const char *file, int line, NSString *format, ...) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    /* Wraps NSLog() with printf() style semantics */
#endif
}
```

**DebugF.h**

```
#ifndef __DEBUGF_H_INCLUDED__
#define __DEBUGF_H_INCLUDED__

#ifdef DEBUG
#define DebugF(args...) __Debug(__FILE__, __LINE__, args)
#else
#define DebugF(...)
#endif /* DEBUG */

void __Debug(const char *file, int line, NSString *fmt, ...);

#endif /* __DEBUGF_H_INCLUDED */
```

**SomeViewController.m**

```
DebugF(@"Got these arguments: %u, %@, %@", 4, anObject, [anObject somethingElse]);
```

Comment: You should include 'returnfloat.h' in 'returnfloat.c' so that the function definition is checked against the function declaration.  Further, in general, 'returnfloat.c' should include 'returnfloat.h' as the first, if not only, header - so that you can be confident it is self-contained.

Comment: Thank you, very much. A part of me has been searching for that information for months, not knowing how exactly to phrase the question!

Comment: @Jonathan: Second example is more complete and demonstrates this, first example has an emphasis on brevity.

Comment: @Jed: And I've just noticed you work for Linode, the best webhost, period. It's been an honour!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Objective-C programmer, but in C world the compiler assumes `int` return type for any undeclared function that current module uses. It looks to me that creating a normal C header file containing:

```
#ifndef _MY_IMPORTANT_HEADER_
#define _MY_IMPORTANT_HEADER_
extern float returnFloat();
#endif
```

and including that into your .m file should make it all work:

```
#include "myheader.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you want:

```
// the c way
float returnFloat() {
   return 10.0;
}

float result = returnFloat();

// the objective-c way
- (float) returnFloat {
   return 10.0;
}

float result = [self returnFloat]; // assuming this is an object
```

Not what you have. You're mixing C function prototypes with Objective-C. Try the C way mentioned above (Should be able to use it in Objective-C code).

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, I'm pretty sure my code is correct :)

**EDIT**: Clarification for all of the downvoters. In his [first revision of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7cf869df-8623-45a9-80d3-5e32217464de/view-source) he made it float returnFloat {} instead of float returnFloat() { }, which prompted my answer.

**EDIT 2**: Apparently that wasn't clear enough. In his first revision of his post, he was mixing the C way of writing function prototypes with the Objective-C way of writing function prototypes. You CAN use C functions in Objective-C, but you CAN'T mix the way of writing their function prototypes, as I explained above. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Are you sure? My understanding is that you can intersperse C and Objective C, although it's not necessarily recommended. Calling C functions from Objective C shouldn't be a problem, surely?

Comment: No yeah, sorry, I reworded my answer. You CAN include C and C++ code in Objective-C programs, but what you were doing was mixing the SYNTAX. You were mixing the C way of writing function prototypes with the objective-c way. Sorry if it sounded confusing at first :)

Comment: I wasn't making things up as I went along. Look at his post edit. He originally had it as float returnFloat { }, not float returnFloat() { }, simple misunderstanding.

Comment: Have slightly reworded the question to make plain that the second code snippet is from *within* an instance method, rather than trying to *be* one.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, *every* C function is a valid Objective C function, and you call it exactly as you would in normal C code.

Comment: Yes, Stephen, but I mean he was mixing the way of writing the C function prototypes with the way of writing the Objective-C prototypes. But it turned out that that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

How did you declare 'returnFloat()' to your Objective-C program?  Does it have a prototype in scope?  If not, then your likely problem is that Objective-C is treating the function as returning an int, not a float, and havoc ensues (or you perceive that zero is returned).

Answer (score -1):

How are you determining that `x` is `0.0000`? A common mistake in debugging is to use the wrong format string in `NSLog()`.

If you are, using `NSLog()`, make sure you're using the `%f` or some variant of it:

```
NSLog(@"x = %f", x);
```

(many people get mixed up and try to use `%i` instead)

EDIT: That's with the assumption that your C function prototype is correct and the lack of parentheses was just a typo here. If not, Blaenk's answer is likely correct.

Comment: Am definitely using the %f flag, have tried in both sprintf and NSLog.

Comment: The lack of parentheses was indeed a typo in the question and is not a problem in the actual code.

Comment: Yeah, the lack of parenthesis was logically the first thing to look at. Instead people decided to downvote me and accuse me of making things up as I go along, hah.

Comment: Not your fault either, typos are common accidents, it's NSD who accused me of making things up and downvoted me. Hope your question gets answered cause it's really intriguing and mysterious!